# MYSQL How to group entries by ID and create a column with grouped entries?

Tags: mysql, database

This is a newbie question, just started studying MySQL. Basically, what I want to do is the following
In the well-know ecommerce db exist several tables that relate to orders and their cost.

I have a table that looks like this

```
OrderID TotalSum
10248   60
10248   140
10248   120
10249   64.26
10249   480
10250   250
10250   420
10250   225
```

I want to group identical `OrderID` and have summed the `TotalSum` for them and store it in separate table. I run the following query

```
SELECT SUM(TotalSum), OrderID FROM orders_data GROUP BY OrderID;
```

and get what I want.

The problem is for some reason (mainly mine stupidity) I can't have the result stored as separate table. What is right query for this?

Comment: So you want to save the result in another db table?

Comment: that's exactly what i want to do

Comment: In general, it's a bad idea to store data that can be easily calculated on the fly. But I accept that sometimes it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *create a **new table***, you can use this:

```
CREATE TABLE anothertbl AS SELECT SUM(TotalSum) as TotalSum, OrderID 
FROM orders_data GROUP BY OrderID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO `your_table` (`column_name_that_holds_OrderIDs`, `column_name_that_holds_SUMs`)
SELECT `OrderID`, SUM(TotalSum) as `TheSum`,  FROM orders_data GROUP BY OrderID;
```